# Ways to access table data from different servers

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I need the data for reportviewer in .NET However the final report involves inner join between different tables in different databasea and different servers. I am currently using XML and dynamic SQL to centralize my code query. What other better methods can i use other than creating multiple similar stored procedures or linking servers (new servers will be added anytime and mapped in a table in one of the server database)

Comment: What about `ADO.Net Entity Framework` ?

Comment: You mean your sp don't know which table it'll join?

Comment: Please, read about linked servers: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms188279.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In your main server that contains a table that has your databases information you can use dynamic SQL with one of this functions:

> **[OPENDATASOURCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179856.aspx) (Transact-SQL)**
>   Provides ad hoc connection information as part of a four-part object name without using a linked server name.
>
> ```
> OPENDATASOURCE ( provider_name, init_string )
> ```
>
> Example:
>   The following example creates an ad hoc connection to the Payroll instance of SQL Server on server London, and queries the AdventureWorks2008R2.HumanResources.Employee table. (Use SQLNCLI and SQL Server will redirect to the latest version of SQL Server Native Client OLE DB Provider.)
>
> ```
> SELECT *
> FROM OPENDATASOURCE('SQLNCLI',
>      'Data Source=London\Payroll;Integrated Security=SSPI')
>      .AdventureWorks2008R2.HumanResources.Employee
> ```

or

> **[OPENROWSET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) (Transact-SQL)** 
>   Includes all connection information that is required to access remote data from an OLE DB data source. This method is an alternative to accessing tables in a linked server and is a one-time, ad hoc method of connecting and accessing remote data by using OLE DB.